# Casually asking whether something particular is the reason

Tags: questions, particle-から, particle-か, casual, explanatory-の

Up until now, I've been under the impression that it's acceptable in casual texting or speech to say ○○から？？ when you're asking whether ○○ is the reason for whatever the topic of conversation is.

For example this (non-native) text, as a response to something someone else texted you that implied they were trying to communicate that they were angry:

そっか、怒ってたのか…もしかしてこの前あれをしたから？

Here, the person that did the あれをした is the writer, and the person who was presumably 怒ってた is the person they're talking to.

But upon searching, I've been unable to find any examples of this pattern, which I suppose could be considered a fragment or part of an inverted sentence.

Is there a more correct way to ask this type of question? Using [Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%20%3F/japanese?), I found examples of similar patterns like からなのか？ and からなのかな？, but (without going through all of the results), no examples simply using からなの？ or から？. I was under the impression that at least one of the latter two was acceptable in this exact situation, but now I'm doubting myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think あれをした is already not completely natural.

If you are asking whether your past action is the reason, either you mention it as あれ (without した) or explicitly say what あれ is.

Also, せい can be used and is probably more common in speech (in such a context).

Thus:

- この前のあれのせい？
- この前のあれのせいで？
- この前のあれのせいなの？
- この前Xしたから？
- この前Xしたからなの？
- この前のことで？

would be more natural.

To me, if you are mature enough male, なの sounds a bit odd. I added この前のことで？, which is perhaps the most natural (or more colloquial こないだのことで？).

---

As a second thought, こないだあれしたから？ may be natural. But I cannot really explain why omitting を makes it natural.

Comment: Thx. I'll admit that for anonymity purposes I changed the sentence significantly from what I originally wanted to write, which was like この間○○したから？ - but in any case, I'll keep in mind that writing こないだ the way it's pronounced and omitting を could make a question ending in から sound natural

Comment: Btw, are you a native speaker? If so, I'll accept your answer right now. Otherwise I'd just be curious for other people's opinions too, but yours still とても参考になりました, so tyvm!!!
<(_ _)>

Comment: Follow-up for clarification: which of the forms you wrote would be appropriate if you're just guessing as to the reason? I.e., when the other person hasn't implied what the reason could be, only that they're angry (but you're pretty sure of what the reason is)

Comment: @weirdalsuperfan I'm a native speaker. For the last question, I suppose こないだのことで？ should fit. It is like *because of the thing (that happened/I did) earlier?* Obviously, when the person says just yes to it, it is vague and it could happen that what you mean and what the person is angry about differ silently. If you want to be sure, just use このまえXしたから？ explicitly.